# asp.net mvc working without view file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a plugable scenario on asp.net mvc. My Layout file contains a method for Head and body. Methods are rendering related plugin. So I have only one Controller/Action (Page/Index) and I dont need any view file for this action. Is that posible working without View file or only Layout file?

Thanks.

Layout example.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> MENU </div>
    <div>
        Plugin.Render("body"); //Render plugin method.
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems an odd situation, but regardless:

It all depends on what you expect your one method to return. If it returns non-HTML (e.g. JSON, any primitive type, ...), you don't need it, obviously.

A HTML-layout is generally rendered via Views. I'm not sure if you can address your Master/Layout page as a view in and of itself. What I would suggest is adding a View file, setting it up with the correct Master/Layout page, **and then basically empty out the view file**.

So you'd have a View file, but it wouldn't have any content in it (except for the Master/Layout page setting).

It'd be slightly more understandable for future developers (although not that much), and I don't see any real downside to this (performance-wise or other).